# Папа Римский или папа римский — сфера употребления официального титулования?

Tags: орфография, прописная, строчная, текст

По правилам, при официальном титуловании наименования Папа Римский, Патриарх и т.д. пишутся с прописной буквы. (Примеры из Грамоты: *Президент РФ Владимир Путин встретился в Ватикане с **Папой Римским** Франциском. В завершении встречи **папа** Франциск попросил передать привет патриарху Кириллу.*) см: http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0+%D0%A0

- Вопрос: а **как понять, что в данном случае использовано официальное титулование и, следовательно, поэтому надо писать наименование с прописной буквы**? Это зависит от стиля текста (официально-деловой, художественный, публицистический) или решения автора? От чего? Из Грамоты (та же ссылка): *Мы пишем с прописных Папа Римский как титулование и папа римский в остальных случаях*... **Что это за остальные случаи?**
- Встречались также написания: патриарх Константинопольский, папа Римский — чем объясняется их написание? Примеры: *Из канонических деяний святителя выделяют 28-е правило..., а также апологию этого правила в посланиях святому Льву, **папе Римскому** (440-461). В ведение **патриарха Константинопольского**, согласно, 28-му правилу, были переданы Церкви Малой Азии, Греции, Черноморья.*

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в русском языке действуют 2 кодекса правил: Розенталя и Лопатина. По Розенталю церковные сановники все пишутся со строчной (в 1956 г. по иному никак), по Лопатину допускается заглавная. Помимо двух кодексов, есть ещё практика употребления, где чуть ли не всё связанное с церковью и верой начинают с большой буквы.

Так что в данном вопросе ставить заглавную или нет, решает сам автор.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, здесь имеется в виду сфера употребления. Прописная уместна тольков официально деловом стиле. В других стилях, например - публицистическом,  используется строчная.

Названия должностей, званий, титулов пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: президент, канцлер, председатель, министр, премьер-министр, заместитель министра, мэр, император, королева, хан, шейх, генеральный секретарь, заслуженный деятель культуры, лауреат Нобелевской премии, посол, атташе, директор, генеральный директор, академик, доктор наук, профессор, член-корреспондент, генерал-майор, командующий войсками, руководитель департамента, заведующий отделом, управляющий делами.

**В официальных текстах названия** высших государственных должностей и титулов пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.: Президент Российской Федерации, Председатель Правительства РФ, Председатель Государственной думы, Премьер-министр Индии, Её Величество Королева Англии. Однако в неофициальных текстах эти названия пишутся со строчной буквы, напр.: выборы президента, выступление председателя Госдумы, распоряжение премьер-министра, приём у королевы.

**(Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006.)**